# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8" in the stuff operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

To store `UTF-8` in varchar field in SQL 2019 we are running existing DDL into new SQL2019 db with `LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` collation.

Whole 30K Line of DDL is executing only a single stuff operation giving error.

```
update ad
   set ad.APPDEFAULTNAME = stuff(APPDEFAULTNAME,len(appdefaultname)-charindex('_', reverse(appdefaultname))+2, len(APPDEFAULTNAME),it.index_title)
  from APP_DEFAULTS ad
  join #index_title it
    on substring(APPDEFAULTNAME,len(appdefaultname)-charindex('_', reverse(appdefaultname))+2,len(APPDEFAULTNAME)) = cast(it.[index] as varchar(30))
```

What could be the reason ??

Comment: To fix this, try setting the collation for the string columns in your temp table.

Comment: @GeorgeMastros Thanks it worked , i changed the collation of #index_title into LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 in DDL.

But i can't understand one thing .. I am creating the DB using LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8  , hoping that everything including tempdb's will be created with that .. but not so

Comment: Temp tables are created in TempDB, not your user database. If you don't specify the collation for your temp tables, it uses the default collation of TempDB. TempDB is recreated every time the SQL Server service is started. When TempDB is created, it uses the default collation of the SQL Server instance.

Comment: use `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` for less typing

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a database collation that is different from the instance collation you should enable [Contained Database Collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations?view=sql-server-ver15), if possible.  This will give you the following behavior, and in particular temp tables will use the DATABASE_DEFAULT collation:

[image]

In Azure SQL Database this is always on, and in SQL Server you enable it by setting your [database containment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15) to "partial".